# Is it possible to specify `--no-binary :all:` in the Pipfile?

Tags: python, pipenv, pipfile

I'd like to switch to [pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv), but converting my current `requirements.txt` is not 1:1.

The `requirements.txt` contains:

```
...
lxml==3.8.0 --no-binary :all:
pandas==0.23.4
...
```

So, when I run `pipenv install` it works well:

```
$ pipenv install
requirements.txt found, instead of Pipfile! Converting…
✔ Success! 
Warning: Your Pipfile now contains pinned versions, if your requirements.txt did. 
We recommend updating your Pipfile to specify the "*" version, instead.
Pipfile.lock not found, creating…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
✔ Success! 
Updated Pipfile.lock (383f9f)!
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (383f9f)…
     ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 44/44 — 00:00:05
To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.
```

...but the generated `Pipfile` only contains:

```
...
lxml = "==3.8.0"
pandas = "==0.23.4"
...
```

Is there a way how to specify the need for `--no-binary :all:` in the `Pipfile`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

pipenv respects any PIP variable and hence supports most of the pip options through `PIP_...` env vars.

While not exactly what you want, but setting `PIP_NO_BINARY=lxml` before running pipenv may be a step in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you! Where is this specified? I couldn't find it in the docs.

Comment: It's a pip, not pipenv feature. You can pass it to pipenv by running, e.g. `PIP_NO_BINARY=lxml pipenv install`